# Jekyll remote theme "Could not find compatible versions" issue

Tags: jekyll-theme

I was about to install Jekyll theme using Remote Theme Method, but couldn't install with this message:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find compatible versions

    Because github-pages >= 135, < 178 depends on minima = 2.1.1
      and github-pages >= 44, < 147 depends on liquid = 3.0.6,
      github-pages >= 44, < 178 requires minima = 2.1.1 or liquid = 3.0.6.
(1) So, because github-pages >= 178 depends on jekyll-sass-converter = 1.5.2
      and github-pages >= 28, < 44 depends on jekyll = 2.4.0,
github-pages >= 28 requires minima = 2.1.1 or liquid = 3.0.6 or
jekyll-sass-converter = 1.5.2 or jekyll = 2.4.0.

    Because github-pages >= 9, < 14 depends on kramdown = 1.2.0
      and github-pages < 9 depends on kramdown = 1.0.2,
      github-pages < 14 requires kramdown = 1.0.2 OR = 1.2.0.
    And because github-pages >= 14, < 32 depends on kramdown = 1.3.1,
      github-pages < 32 requires kramdown = 1.0.2 OR = 1.2.0 OR = 1.3.1.
And because github-pages >= 28 requires minima = 2.1.1 or liquid = 3.0.6 or
jekyll-sass-converter = 1.5.2 or jekyll = 2.4.0 (1),
one of minima = 2.1.1 or liquid = 3.0.6 or jekyll-sass-converter = 1.5.2
or jekyll = 2.4.0 or kramdown = 1.0.2 OR = 1.2.0 OR = 1.3.1 must be true.
    And because jekyll >= 4.3.0 depends on jekyll-sass-converter >= 2.0, < 4.0,
jekyll >= 4.3.0 requires minima = 2.1.1 or liquid = 3.0.6 or kramdown =
1.0.2 OR = 1.2.0 OR = 1.3.1.
    And because jekyll >= 4.3.0 depends on kramdown >= 2.3.1, < 3.A
      and jekyll >= 3.5.0 depends on liquid ~> 4.0,
      jekyll >= 4.3.0 requires minima = 2.1.1.
    So, because Gemfile depends on jekyll ~> 4.3.2
      and Gemfile depends on minima ~> 2.5,
      version solving has failed.
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to change version numbers of following code in `Gemfile`, but it doesn't work. Do I change into wrong number? Or this solution is wrong?

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pages.github.com/versions/

```
Dependency  Version
jekyll      3.9.3
```

Change to `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.9.3"` and you should be good to go.